# Swipe to delete not working with left to right swipe

Tags: ios, uitableview, ipad, swipe

I have a strange problem with swipe-to-delete in my iPad app.  I have a UITableView control hosted within a UIViewController.  The UIViewController is hosted in the 'Master' pane of a UISplitViewController.  I have implemented commitEditingStyle to get the swipe-to-delete function and this is working fine if I swipe from right to left I get the 'Delete' button appear.  But when the app is in landscape mode left to right swipes do not get detected.  In portrait mode it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it was because I was setting presentsWithGesture to YES on my UISplitViewController - this affects the left-to-right swipes made when in landscape mode.